# Pool worker to miner mapping

Tags: mining, mining-pools

On mining pools like Suprnova, one connects to a worker they create, with a username and password.

What I'm wondering is, if you're running a miner should you create a different worker for every mining host you have, or are there no disadvantages to having more than one host (potentially hundreds) logged in to the same worker account while mining?